# How to report spam to blacklists

Tags: spam, blacklist

Is there a central place to report spam to various blacklists ?

I regularly report to spamcop, but

1. I do not see the addresses I reported as listed. (I guess nobody else bothers with my regular spammer. After being frustrated with bayes and spammcop, I blocked its /24 subnet)
2. Spamcop is only a single service. I want to make the spammer known to a large number of services, and hopefully blocked by many of them.

I looked for some other blacklists to report to, but the ones I looked do not consider user submissions (or they hide it well)

Comment: Sad to say reporting legitimate serial spammers to Spamcop doesn't seem to do jack s*it - even though I do it AND I take great pleasure in reporting spammers, but I seriously doubt that individual reporting does a damn thing. I wish it would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no central spam blacklist service that I'm aware of. However, you could gather a comprehensive list of blacklists and then search each of them for user submission forms here's a small sampling:

- http://www.ahbl.org/
- http://www.backscatterer.org
- http://barracudacentral.org/rbl
- http://dnsbl.burnt-tech.com/
- http://cbl.abuseat.org/
- https://www.dan.me.uk/dnsbl
- http://www.dnsbl.info/

...to name a few. Check out a few lists of black lists to get a much larger bunch. For example:

- http://www.moensted.dk/spam/
- http://ipindex.homelinux.net/index.php?action=check_on_dnsbl

Comment: For this comment to be useful, the URLs should be the manual "report" forms. (But most of them do not have such thing).

Answer (score 3):

Most blacklists use multiple methods to determine spammers. It would really suck if all it took was 1 complaint to put you on a blacklist. So they use honeypot email addresses and all sorts of heuristics to determine if somebody is spamming. They can function pretty well without submissions. But nothing is perfect. That's why it's good to rely on multiple methods for determining spam.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. If you look at spamcop's policy, reports from two different users get a 24hour listing. More submissions mean longer listings. I already use a combination of blacklists, spamassassin and hand crafted rules for postfix/spamasassassin. I want to hurt spammers more by getting them in more blacklists, thus I am looking for better ways of reporting spammers.

Answer (score 2):

You could always report them to their ISP.  Take a look at the whois (or tracert) results, and see who is providing them with bandwidth/transit.  Reporting to them would probably get a better response then reporting to some random blacklist.

Comment: Good point! I approve.

Answer (score 2):

You coud try this link

http://members.spamcop.net/

1. Register first
2. Forward email as attachment to the specified addresses
3. You will receive a confirmation message for processing.

Answer (score 0):

Late for the game. But for everyone that is still interested in this topic, we could report spammers by forwarding the identified e-mail to spam@uce.gov:

> Anyone who wish to forward unwanted or deceptive spam to the FTC should use the spam@uce.gov (link sends e-mail) address. Whenever you complain about spam, it's important to include the full email header.

You can find more info in https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0038-spam#report

And more options in http://www.thewindowsclub.com/report-scams-phishing-spam

Hope this help.